# Magento - Add file type attribute to order

Tags: magento

I want users to be able to attach a file to their order and to see this attachment in the backend. I have tried the following:

```
<?php


require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

try{

$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
$attribute  = array(
    'type'          => 'file',
    'label'         => 'Recept',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'user_defined'  =>  true
);
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'recept_attribute', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();

}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But get the error: Invalid column definition data

I guess the type is wrong? Where can i see which types I can use on an order and is this the right approach?

(I know it is quite easy to add this as a custom field in per order item in the backend but that is not what I want)